# How I can display 4random numbers in 4 textboxes in C# forms?

Tags: c#, random

I want to make a math app in windows forms and I want to display 4 random numbers in 4 textboxes but when I use:

```
 Random randomNumitor1 = new Random();
        int rndmNMT1 = randomNumitor1.Next(1, 10);
        textBox2.Text = rndmNMT1.ToString();
        Random randomNumitor2 = new Random();
        int rndmNMT2 = randomNumitor2.Next(1, 10);
        textBox4.Text = rndmNMT2.ToString();
        Random randomNumarator1 = new Random();
        int rndmNMRT1 = randomNumarator1.Next(1, 10);
        textBox1.Text = rndmNMRT1.ToString();
        Random randomNumarator2 = new Random();
        int rndmNMRT2 = randomNumarator2.Next(1, 10);
        textBox3.Text = rndmNMRT2.ToString();
```

the app is generating the 4 same numbers. Can somebody help me to modify this code to display 4 different numbers.
I want to say I will use it for a fraction resolving exercise.
Help me please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new Random(), but use the same Random() instead.

Suprisingly, using `randomNumitor1` these 4 times will result in different numbers.

Comment: WOOOOOOW! IT IS WORKING! :))
Thank you, man! You were so quick! 
Have a great day!